# Equivalent of matlab "ans" and running shell commands

Tags: python, matlab, shell

These days, I'm transitiong from Matlab to Python after using Matlab/Octave for more than ten years. I have two quick questions:

1. In the Python interactive mode, is there anything corresponding to Matlab's `ans`?
2. How can I run shell commands in the Python interactive mode? Of course, I can use `os.system()`, but in Matlab we may run shell commands just by placing `!` before the actual command. Is there anything similar in Python?

Answer (score 7):

Python interactive mode is Python. You will need to use `os.system` or an equivalent. Alternately, you can suspend Python with Ctrl-Z, and get back into it with `fg`. (Assuming UNIX-like environment.)

The last evaluated expression is saved in the variable `_`:

```
>>> 1 + 2
3
>>> _ * 4
12
```

Comment: I didn't know about `_` being the last evaluated expression.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng In fact, in ipython you can get all past results with _ and its index value _1, _2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Python equivalent of the Matlab `ans` is as follows:

```
ans = (your_expression)
```

In other words, the most recent expression is not always automatically saved to a default reference, so just save it manually as normal. As @Amadan points out, expressions are sometimes saved to `_`, but not always. The best practice for reliability and clarity is to save it yourself.

To run shell commands, you can use `os.system()` as you suggested. However, that is deprecated, so you should look into the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: "the most recent expression is not automatically saved to a default reference" is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like it's only for certain things, though - `print()` doesn't save `None` to `_`. I'll edit this information in, though.

Comment: `None` is not saved. `1 + 2 (3); _ (3); None; _ (3)`

Comment: I think that's reason enough to avoid it, on top of the reduced readability. However, I definitely didn't know it saved anything at all by default. Good info! :)

Comment: Readability is not an issue given that this is for interactive use. You do an evaluation, then remember that you needed the return value for a further evaluation. In non-interactive use, you go up and add a variable assignment. In REPL, having the previous value is a great convenience (and as reading through someone's old REPL history is not a normal programming practice, it is a non-issue).

Comment: Also, if your command fails and you get `None` for an answer, you are not likely to want to reuse it; thus, the fact that `None` is not saved is a feature, not a bug. Remember that since `_` only works in REPL, and not in a proper code written in a file, and will thus always have a human with decision-making power after each evaluation, you will never get into a situation where you will use `_` and expect `None` to be in it.

Comment: `my_dictionary.get('ID'); if _:...`. Which you could of course work around by setting a default value for the `get()`, but at that point you might as well save it normally anyway. I agree that `_` provides definite convenience in some cases, but I still think it's better to explicitly save any values you'd like to keep, even in the interactive interpreter.

Comment: Why would you ever do that in interactive console? They are two commands; why would you not execute them as two commands, if you know one of them can fail? Why would you execute `if` in an interactive console at all, given that you have a brain and are interacting with the interpreter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87431/discussion-between-tigerhawkt3-and-amadan).

Comment: Sorry, laptop lost power, can't access chat. Anyway, yes: `_` is for simple cases for when you forget to assign a variable, and don't want to or can't use history.

Comment: Consider this: `insert_row_and_return_id(row_data)` and you forgot to assign it and need that ID. You can't use history because you'll get a duplicate row. `id = _` saves your butt.

Comment: I'm not saying it's useless. I'm saying I wouldn't recommend making a habit of using it, except where it's really needed (such as your example).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the IPython shell (now part of the jupyeter project).  In the IPython shell you can also run system commands using `!`, although many basic commands (like `ls` or `cd`) work without even needing to `!`.  Unlike in MATLAB, you don't need to pass it as a string (although you can).  So `!ls` works fine in IPython, while in MATLAB you would need to do `!'ls'`.  Further, you can assign the results to a variable in IPython, which you can't do in MATLAB.  So `a = !ls` works in IPython but not in MATLAB.  Further, if you use `!!`, the result is returned in a form easily usable in Python.  So `!!ls` returns a list of file names.

IPython still uses the `_` notation for getting the previous result (except, as with Python, `None` is counted as "no result" and thus is not recorded).  You can also get the second-to-last result with `__` and the third-to-last with `___`.  Further, IPython puts a number next to each line in the command prompt.  To get the result of a particular line, just do `_n` where `n` is the number.  So to get the result of the 3rd command, which has the number `3` next to it, just do `_3`.  This still doesn't work if the result is `None`, though.

It has a ton of features.  You can get the previous input (as a string) with `_i` (and so on, following the same pattern as with the outputs).  You can time code with `%timeit` and `%%timeit`.  You can jump into the debugger after encountering an error.